# How to refresh (Refresh All button in excel sheet) the excel sheet using openXML in C#

Tags: c#, excel, refresh, openxml

I have an Excel Sheet in which while Clicking Data->RefreshAll dynamically update the cells and values after giving credentials.I need to done the functionality of Refresh All button Via c# code using openXml .

Answer (score 0):

So you would have to open the workbook with Excel object model and then call the Workbook.RefreshAll method.

Comment: Can you put some code snippet for making it more understandable .I am using openxml to read Excel Data since it have to uploaded un Azure

Comment: Open XML doesn't provide some abilities doing like this. We generally work with Open XML SDK to store date, change formulas and so on, but calculation which is Refresh All Button do doesn't included. Do google search for using interop.Excel there is plenty of demos how to use it